# How to remove original email message in reply message using php?

Tags: php, string, replace

I am using PHP to get the email from the POP3 server. However, some emails also contain the original message which I sent to them.

How do I remove the original message, so the PHP script will only get the reply message?

For example:

*Email sent from A to B*

```
A
11:08 PM (1 minute ago)

to B 
how are you?
```

*Email replied from B to A*

```
11:08 PM (0 minutes ago)

to A 
I am fine

> On Sun, Mar 8, 2015 at 11:08 PM, Ryan Ho <ryan@incube.com.hk> wrote:
>  how are you?
```

I would like to remove those wordings *"On Sun Mar 8,.... to how are you?"*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can save the email in a file, then you can remove all the lines starting with **>** using a regular expression. 
This is because all lines from the original message start with the symbol `>`, including the text:
*On Sun, Mar 8, ... wrote: how are you?*

Here is the code doing that:

```
<?php
$filename="email-full.txt";
$outfile="email-noreply.txt";
$string = file_get_contents($filename);
$array = explode("\n",$string);
foreach($array as $arr) {
            if(!(preg_match("/^>/",$arr))) {
                            $output[] = $arr;
            }
}

$out = implode("\n",$output);
file_put_contents($outfile,$out);
?>
```